# How to do one octomino?

Tags: binary-variable, graphs

Here are all the 369 octominoes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octomino

If I have an 8x8 area, how to create one octomino, any of those 369 and any rotation and mirroring is allowed?

I have tried several linearized and/or tricks but those produced sometimes correct sometimes wrong solutions. How to make constraints so the eight binary ones are always connected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to model a connected subgraph, with $8$ nodes, of an $8 \times 8$ grid graph.
Let binary decision variable $x_{ij}$ indicate whether undirected edge $\{i,j\}\in E$ is selected.
Let binary decision variable $y_i$ indicate whether node $i$ is selected.
Let binary decision variable $s_i$ indicate whether node $i$ is selected as the source node.  Let nonnegative decision variable $f_{ij}$ be the flow across directed arc $(i,j)\in A$.  The idea is to enforce connectivity by sending one unit of flow from the source to each other selected node.  The constraints are:
\begin{align}
\sum_i y_i &= 8 \tag1\label1 \\
x_{ij} &\le y_i &&\text{for all $\{i,j\}\in E$} \tag2\label2 \\
x_{ij} &\le y_j &&\text{for all $\{i,j\}\in E$} \tag3\label3 \\
x_{ij} &\ge y_i + y_j - 1 &&\text{for all $\{i,j\}\in E$} \tag4\label4 \\
\sum_i s_i &= 1 \tag5\label5 \\
s_i &\le y_i && \text{for all $i$} \tag6\label6 \\
f_{ij} + f_{ji} &\le 7 x_{ij} && \text{for all $\{i,j\}\in E$} \tag7\label7 \\
\sum_{(i,j) \in A} f_{ij} - \sum_{(j,i)\in A} f_{ji}
   &= 8 s_i - y_i &&\text{for all $i$} \tag8\label8
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} selects $8$ nodes.
Constraints \eqref{2} through \eqref{4} link the node variables to the edge variables.
Constraint \eqref{5} selects one source node.
Constraint \eqref{6} forces the source node to be a selected node.
Constraint \eqref{7} allows flow only on selected edges.
Constraint \eqref{8} enforces flow balance.

Because a connected graph must have at most one more node than the number of edges, an optional constraint is $$\sum_{\{i,j\}\in E} x_{ij} \ge 7.$$

Note that you can relax $x$ to be nonnegative because it will automatically take values in $\{0,1\}$ if $y$ does.

Comment: Thank You. Could You or someone else comment how many x and f variables will be? I understand there is 64 y and s variables.

Comment: $|E|=8\times7\times2$ and $|A|=2|E|$

Comment: Great answer! Did you use similar formulation in [the greenhouse problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/107029/79445)? And do you think this formulation has any connection with MTZ formulation?