How to formulate this chessboard problem?
In this post, the author proposed a CP model to solve the problem "How can we split the chess board into two equal surface parts?" (More precisely, the author finds all solutions of the problem). Here are 6 possible solutions for a 8x8 board:

It does not seem easy to enforce the contiguity constraints. What would be a MIP formulation for this problem?

My try:

$x_{p,c}\in\{0,1\}$: binary variable that takes value $1$ if cell $p$ is assigned color $c\in \{1,2\}$
All cells must be assigned exactly one color:
$$
\sum_c x_{p,c} = 1 \quad \forall p
$$
The board must be split in $2$:
$$
\sum_p x_{p,1} = \sum_p x_{p,2}
$$


The CP formulation in that linked post is really a MIP formulation. See also https://or.stackexchange.com/a/10789/500
